# GAE Java isn't downloading refreshed data of requested URL

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm currently downloading data from an URL and splitting the content, just to show it again on my appspot. The data from the URL is changed several times a day. My appspot though, stays the same.
I thought that I solved the problem, by setting the pragma on "no-cache" and the date of the header to 0.

This is how my code looks like and it works:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        resp.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

> Content-Length:15983 - Content-Type:text/html - Date:Tue, 20 Dec 2011
>   14:06:53 GMT - Expires:Thu 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT - Pragma:no-cache
>   Server:Google Frontend

But my appspot still doesn't fetch the refreshed data from the URL like it should. What am I missing here? Since nothing has changed, since I've changed the response Headers, I've got no clue what else to do.

Comment: One option is to change the request URL slightly - e.g. add '?' and a random number - to prevent caching on the GAE side.

Comment: How can I change the request URL slightly and still access it? Let's suppose that this is my URL: 
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
BufferedReader reader....
What would this URL look like, with your request example?

Comment: @dodinvents - Usually, appending some unused parameter doesn't stop it from being served - e.g. add '?n=123' or if there are already parameters append '&n=123'. So `new URL("google.com?n=123");`

Comment: @sje397 - Thanks a lot! I'm going to try that.

Comment: Show us the rest of your code. Is the server you're downloading the page from setting caching headers? Also, it's not "your appspot", it's your App Engine app. appspot is just the domain.

Comment: @NickJohnson Thanks for your reply. sje397's method has worked. And yeah, I meant App and not appspot ;)

Answer (score 0):

When I was writing webapps I always used the "Cache-Control" header in my servlets and JSP.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
}
```

For reference here you want to refer to section 14.9 in RFC 2616.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that and it didn't work. It seems like the GAE doesn't care for the resp.setHeader... I'm going to try sje397 method though.